# why some signals are bound and other unbound?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am starting with `PyQt`  and was looking at grouping the signals in a dict (I will have several / many of them and I wanted to initialize them in a loop as opposed to doing this line by line).

I noticed however that the dict values are unbound, while bare variables are bound:

```
In [7]: from PyQt4 import QtCore

In [10]: class Update(QtCore.QObject):
   ....:     a = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)
   ....:     b = {'x': QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)}
   ....:

In [11]: r = Update()

In [12]: r.a
Out[12]: <bound signal a of Update object at 0x02D1B170>

In [13]: r.b
Out[13]: {'x': <unbound signal >}
```

Why the difference?

Comment: If you want to initialise/connect signals in a loop, put one in a wrapper class (or subclass an appropriate exiting class) and instantiate the objects in a loop (and store them in a list/dict). Based on what you've said you want to do in the comments below, you probably want to subclass `QLabel` and add a signal there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)` creates an attribute

`b = {'x': QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)}` is storing an `QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)` object in an attribute of the object, so it will not be an attribute itself.

Comment: Thanks, I now understand. Is there a best practice to initialize many signals, then? I would like to avoid having 20 or 50  lines like the `a = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)` in my example, thus my attempt at initializing in an iteration of a dict.

Comment: @WoJ, i am not overly familiar with pyqt but having a look at how signals are normally created I did not see any example other than creating  class instances.

Comment: @WoJ. Creating twenty custom signals for one class would be highly unusual, so I doubt whether there could ever be a "best practice" for it. You'd probably have to resort to some metaclass hackery to get your idea to work, so the solution would very likely be worse than the original problem.

Comment: @ekhumoro: I am writing a simple display which uses several (many) QLabels - there is not user interaction, just updates of the labels. This is why I use a single class.

Comment: @WoJ. That doesn't expain why you would need twenty custom signals. I suspect there must be something wrong with the design of your application.